# Heroku won't run mongolab app

Tags: heroku, mlab

I am following the exact instructions from [this freecodecamp post](https://forum.freecodecamp.com/t/guide-for-using-mongodb-and-deploying-to-heroku/19347/6)(except that I haven't stored and used the connection URI .env variable), yet the app's webpage shows '*An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.*'

Below is what is in my app.js, and I am absolutely positive that the username and password are correct and of the correct format.

```js
//lets require/import the mongodb native drivers.
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

//We need to work with "MongoClient" interface in order to connect to a mongodb server.
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// Connection URL. This is where your mongodb server is running.

//(Focus on This Variable)
var url = 'mongodb://user1:123456@ds139959.mlab.com:39959/url-shortener';
//'mongodb://user1:123456@ds139959.mlab.com:39959/url-shortener';     
//(Focus on This Variable)

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connection established to', url);

    // do some work here with the database.

    //Close connection
    db.close();
  }
});
```

This is the log messages after i typed "heroku logs"

> 2017-06-26T13:11:15.395121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=herokudatabaseprovisioning.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=f2f3d85e-154c-4169-8c8c-9a1f4bdee05c fwd="137.132.242.118"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2017-06-26T13:11:16.634793+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=herokudatabaseprovisioning.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=01d79a9d-0088-4dac-b582-79e08c8e0858 fwd="137.132.242.118
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Also, I've scrutinized a few stack overflow answers addressing this error type from heroku logs, yet all those are arised from using node.js' native server `.listen()` method, none of those addressed about how to resolve the issue of using mongodb's `MongoClient.connect()`method

How to resolve this? I have been stuck in this for 2 weeks, seriously.
This is [the repo](https://github.com/hesingon/FFCdbprovision.git) of the whole source codes in github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through your package.json . You didnt specify your scripts parameter. Here's a modified version. Also be sure to rename your procfile to Procfile.

```
{
    "name": "trial",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Test for Hesington",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "main": "app.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "mongodb": "^2.2.29"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.3",
        "npm": "5.0.2"
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/hesingon/FFCdbprovision.git"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/hesingon/FFCdbprovision/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/hesingon/FFCdbprovision#readme"
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. I just changed the file to `web: node app.js`, yet it still doesn't seem to be working :/

Comment: Your package.json file also had issues. Ive corrected them and edited my previous post.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've managed to get it to output the expected log messages from command `heroku logs --tail`, whereby in this case `2017-06-27T02:38:58.857556+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection established to mongodb://user1:123456@ds139959.mlab.com:39959/url-shortener`. However, when I open the app page with command `heroku open`, I still see the application error being displayed. Is this normal as I didn't serve any html file?

Comment: Yes its normal, you also haven't placed any operation before your db.close so the application terminates on clean exit.